# How to bypass "Other users cannot see your changes..." window when closing Sharepoint Excel document?

Tags: vba, excel, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I'm trying to open an Excel workbook in a Sharepoint document library, modify it, and close it without checking in the changes.

This is the code I'm running:

```
Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
xlApp.Visible = true;
Excel.Workbook bk = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("http://sharepointSite/" + filename,false);
Excel.Worksheet sht = bk.Sheets["Some Data"];
sht.Range["A1"].Value= DateTime.Now.ToString();
bk.Save();
xlApp.EnableEvents = false;
bk.Close(false);
xlApp.EnableEvents = true;
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = true;
xlApp.Quit();
```

When I call `bk.Close(false), Excel shows a Yes/No/Cancel popup window with this message:

```
Other users cannot see your changes until you check in.  Do you want to check in now?
```

Since I don't want to check in yet, I click "No", and that works fine.  But I'd really like to automate this.  Is there a way to detect this popup and click "No", or better yet, bypass the window entirely?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was resolved by setting `xlApp.Visible` to `False` immediately prior to closing the workbook, as follows:

```
xlApp.Visible = false;
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
bk.Close(false);
```